# Why am I getting an npm error while trying to install Parcel?

Tags: npm, parceljs

I'm trying to install [Parcel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel) but when I run the command `npm install --save-dev parcel` I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\\ javascript\\Resorce &  practices\\complete-javascript \\17-Modern-JS-Modules-Tooling\\starter\\node_modules@parcel\\watcher
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! 'practices\\complete-javascript\\17-Modern-JS-Modules-Tooling\\starter\\node_modules.bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'E:\\javascript\\node-gyp-build\\bin.js'
npm ERR!     at Function.Module.\_resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint \[as runMain\] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: \[\]
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\\Users\\esrak\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache_logs\\2022-03-25T19_58_11_366Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lays on your path.

```
E:\ javascript\Resorce & practices
```

should be

```
E:\ javascript\Resorce_practices
```

Comment: It is also recommended to use the least amount of spaces possible in your folder and file names (usually none). Instead, replace spaces with dashes (`-`) or underscores (`_`).